# Edit Query does not change anything in DB

Tags: php, sql

This code is supposed to update an article that's already in the DB with the changes made at Edit webpage, but it does not work.  It displays the current article, but when I make changes and click "save" nothing changes.

```
mysql_select_db("scms", $con );  
$show_world="show_world";
define("IMG_URL", "http://localhost/project/show/show_home/images/");
define("ABS_PATH",dirname(__FILE__));
define("IMG_PATH",dirname(__FILE__)."/");
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "select * FROM $show_world where id = $id";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if(isset($_POST['save'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $topic = $_POST['topic'];
    $author = $_POST['author'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $picture = $_POST['picture'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $sql = "UPDATE $show_world SET topic='".$topic."',author='".$author."', content='".$content."', date='".$date."' ";
```

Comment: Is there more to that Sql query such as `WHERE id = $id` ?

Comment: so I should add `WHERE id =$id` at the end of that query?

Comment: Stop using mysql_* functions, they are [being deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Use mysqli or PDO and bind variables instead. **Don't put unfiltered user input into SQL**.

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing the variable for table name like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE {$show_world} SET topic='".$topic.....
```

One more thing: your code is vulnerable to sql injections ! Try to escape the user inputs, before updating it in the database.